# ¿Cómo elimino archivos cuyo nombre encaja con un patrón determinado?

Tags: bash, unix

Tengo la siguiente lista de archivos

```
01-05-2012.csv
01-17-2012.csv
01-27-2012.csv
02-01-2012.csv
02-02-2012.csv
02-03-2012.csv
02-04-2012.csv
02-05-2012.csv
04-02-2012.csv
04-04-2012.csv
04-05-2012.csv
```

Me gustaría eliminar los que empiezan por `01` y `02`

Comment: En que sistema operativo estas?

Comment: Manjaro kde plasma

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que haz intentado? ¿Qué es lo que haz buscado para que se te pueda ayudar con una duda en concreto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Planteo otra alternativa al resto de respuestas usando el comando find.

Poseo los siguientes ficheros:

```
$ -> ls -1
01-05-2012.csv
02-05-2012.csv
02-06-2012.csv
02-07-2012.csv
03-03-2012.csv
04-03-2012.csv
```

Ejecuto el siguiente comando:

```
$ -> find . -type f -name '0[1,2]*' -exec rm {} \;
```

Ha eliminado el resto de ficheros:

```
$ -> ls -1
03-03-2012.csv
04-03-2012.csv
```

Explicación:

- `.` : El punto en este caso es la ubicación. Estoy situado ya en la carpeta donde quiero eliminar los ficheros. En caso de no estar ubicado, puedes utilizar la ruta relativa/absoluta según necesites, por ejemplo: `find /home/user/carpetaDondeSeEncuentranLosFicheros`
- `type` : Se utiliza para indicar el tipo de dato que buscas. `f` para ficheros, `d` para directorios, etc.
- `name` : Se usa para el patrón del nombre que buscas. En este caso buscamos los que comiencen por 0 seguido de un 1 o un 2 y luego con el asterisco indicas que puede tener otro caracter.
- `exec` : Se utiliza para ejecutar un comando, en este caso, `rm`.
- Punto y coma `;` : Se usa para terminar el comando invocado por exec.
- Llaves `{}` : Las llaves son reemplazadas internamente por cada fichero encontrado durante el comando `find`.

Comment: si bien es útil, esto creo que es excesivo pues eliminará también ficheros que haya en subdirectorios

Comment: Efectivamente, así como presenta diferencia en como va eliminando los ficheros cuando no se usa el + en el find. Un rm de hecho ya cumple lo requerido. Un saludo.

Comment: lo bueno de usar `find` es que siempre funcionará, mientras que `rm` con algún `*` puede fallar si el `*` se expande a un número excesivamente grande (del orden de miles)

Answer (score 2):

Puedes decir:

```
rm 0{1,2}-*
```

Esto eliminará todo lo que empiece por 01 o 02.

Si quieres restringir a los qie sean csv, usa:

```
rm 0{1,2}-*.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Te colocas en el directorio desde la terminal y con el comando
En linux

```
rm -f 01-*, 02-*
```

En windows

```
del 01-*, 02-*
```